# Автозагрузка классов + composer + cli mode

Tags: php, консоль

Есть такой простой автозагрузчик:

```
<?php
function classes($class)
{
    $app = dirname(__DIR__);
    try {
        if (!@include_once $app . "/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php") {
            throw new Exception("Файл не найден!");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if (php_sapi_name() != "cli")
            die("Ошибка подключения класса {$class} " . $e->getMessage());
        else
            echo "Ошибка загрузки класса стандартным загрузчиком";
    }
}


    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
spl_autoload_register('classes');
?>
```

При работе в штатном режиме все ок. Классы подтягивает.
Но при запуска с консоли имею ряд проблем которых иметь не хочется, так как работаю с websocket (с [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman)).

> ```
> include_once(/var/www/www-root/data/www/site.com/React/EventLoop/LoopInterface.php): failed to open stream:
> No such file or directory in file 
> /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.com/system/Class.php on line 7
> ```

Я так понимаю, что два эти загрузчика не хотят "дружить".
Но, кстати, вебсокет поднялся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверьте с начала есть ли файл под загружайте + зачем autoload composer-a в регистр кидать + ну и если он не загрузит значит ваш найдет. И не надо в autoload'е что то выкидывать класс может быть подгружен и в ручную

```
<?php
require_once $app . '/vendor/autoload.php';

function classes($class)
{
    $app = dirname(__DIR__);

    $file = $app . "/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php";

    if (file_exists($file) {
      require_once $file;
    } 
};

spl_autoload_register('classes');
?>
```

Comment: Согласен, я вытянул его с функции, это логично, да

Comment: Добавил в index.php ещё 
chdir(__DIR__ ); // задаем директорию выполнение скрипта